# Bug in Gradle Libgdx When try to Drag and Drop

Tags: java, android, eclipse, gradle, libgdx

I try code that taken from libgdx :
https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/tests/gdx-tests/src/com/badlogic/gdx/tests/DragAndDropTest.java

if i not using Gradle, there is no problem and image can be moved freely.
Shown in : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qQbe-USYyv0

But i meet some problem when using Gradle. image very hard to be moved and it stop when reach corner of screen, 
Shown in : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Rty9fDdAPwg

What's Wrong actually?
And How come the outcome become different?

I try the project in dekstop and Android, same behaviour..

For your information (maybe useful)
I use Eclipse Luna 4.4

Image when i import to my eclipse :
http://i1161.photobucket.com/albums/q519/Luthfan30/justdothis_zps527765b3.png

When i generate using Libgdx Gradle Window :
http://i1161.photobucket.com/albums/q519/Luthfan30/dolikethis_zps2f546ecc.png
(for your information, even when i  check box2d only, still same problem)

Please point me for the error.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Finally i found the answer why behaviour can different each other.

It depend on What version of Libgdx that you use.

FOr succesfully drag = version 0.9
For failed drag = version 1.4 (latest version now)

Comment: version 1.6.2 which I've just tried also works for successfully drag, I was using version 1.5 and with that version drag fails.